# How do you configure an Openshift service to distribute work to the pod with the least active connections?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, load-balancing

The Openshift documentation is absolutely abysmal. I can't find direct documentation for any of the objects that are available.

I did find a section in the Kubernetes docs that seems to describe the ability to do something like this...

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/

But it wasn't super clear how this translates to OoenShift, or how to actually implement this IPVS mode for a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on Slack, but short version it is not an option for this user given their situation.

For others, IPVS does support this but it is enabled and configured at a global level. A better option is usually a userspace proxy, often via the Ingress system.